# Lookup field from two objects up from a field

Tags: apex, query, custom-object, lookup

Hi I am creating an after insert Trigger of an object and I am facing a small problem when creating a related record from other object when the trigger from other object is triggered. The situation is the next one:

First Object Subject:

- Name Programming l

Second Object Deliverable:

- Name: Practice l (in roman number i.e: Practice l ,practice ll, practice lll...)
- Subject (Lookup from object Subject): Programming l

Third Object Course Subject:

- Name: Programming l.
- Subject (Lookup from object Subject): Programming l)

Fourth Object Course Deliverable:

- Name: Practice 3
- Course Subject (Lookup from object Course Subject): Programming l
- Deliverable (Lookup from object Deliverable) ****** : Practice lll

So I want that the after insert of the Course Subject its related list (Course Deliverable) to be created.

******  I am having problems with this field in my code I am not being able to make a query to find this Lookup field. Because the Deliverable record must have the subject of the course subject and get his counterpart in roman number. For example. I want to create the course deliverable record:

Name: Practice 3

Course Subject: Programming l

Deliverable: Practice lll

In total I have to create 5 Practices and my code is this one:

```
public class UAN_CourseSubjectHelper {
public static void  createCourseDeliverables(List<Course_Subject__c> courseSubjectList) {

    List<Entregable_del_Curso__c> CourseDeliverablesToCreate = new List<Entregable_del_Curso__c>();

    Map<Id,Course_Subject__c> mapIdSubjectFromCourseSubject = new Map<Id,Course_Subject__c>();

    for(Course_Subject__c iCourseDeliverable: courseSubjectList){
        mapIdSubjectFromCourseSubject.put(iCourseDeliverable.Subject__c,iCourseDeliverable);
    }

    map<Id,Deliverable__c> subjectIdwithDeliverables = new map<Id,Deliverable__c>();

    List<Deliverable__c> deliverablesList = [Select Id,UAN_Subject__c FROM Deliverable__c WHERE UAN_Subject__c IN : mapIdSubjectFromCourseSubject.keySet()];

    if(deliverablesList != null && deliverablesList.size() >0){
        for(Deliverable__c iDeliverable : deliverablesList){
            subjectIdwithDeliverables.put(iDeliverable.UAN_Subject__c,iDeliverable);
        }
    }
    for(Course_Subject__c iCourseDeliverable: courseSubjectList){


        Integer totalPractices = 5;
        for(Integer i=1; i<=totalPractices; i++){
            String romanSufix = UAN_SubjectHelper.intoRoman(i);
            Entregable_del_Curso__c courseDeliverable = new Entregable_del_Curso__c();
            courseDeliverable.Name = 'Practica ' + String.valueOf(i);
            courseDeliverable.Course_Subject__c = iCourseDeliverable.Subject__c;

            String nameDeliverable = 'Practice ' + romanSufix;
            courseDeliverable.Deliverable__c = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Deliverable__c,UAN_Subject__c WHERE
             Name =:nameDeliverable AND UAN_Subject__c =:iCourseDeliverable.Subject__c].Id;

        }
    }
}
```

}

I also had this error when i tried to deploy:

[image]

Can anybody tell me how to find this field in apex code?

Comment: The issue is in `[SELECT Id, Name FROM Deliverable__c,UAN_Subject__c WHERE
             Name =:nameDeliverable AND UAN_Subject__c =:iCourseDeliverable.Subject__c].Id;` line. You have written from `Deliverable__c,UAN_Subject__c` Can you put exact one object.

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala can you explain this a bit more?

Comment: You are using From Deliverable__c, UAN_Subject__c but Soql query   only accepts one object(Either Deliverable__c or UAN_Subject__c) but you cannot but both .